# Operating on an Array of objects versus operating on a single object containing arrays of parameters?

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine, path-finding

I am thinking on making a path finding System and each node must contain Positional Data, The movement cost associated with that and so on. Which Approach would be more Performant, as my target Platform is for mobiles.

Which is better on the performance side of things?

This:

```
public Class Test{
int x;
float y;
string z;
}

.
.
.

Test[] tests = new Test[100];

for(int i=0; i< 100; ++i){
tests[i].x = 0;
tests[i].y = 0.5f;
tests[i].z = "Hello:";
}
```

Or this:

```
public Class Test{
int[] x;
float[] y;
string[] z;
}

.
.
.

Test tests = new Test;
test.x = new int[100];
test.y = new float[100];
test.z = new string[100];

for(int i=0; i< 100; ++i){
tests.x[i] = 0;
tests.y[i] = 0.5f;
tests.z[i] = "Hello:";
}
```

Comment: Have you tried profiling it?

Comment: Go with the first version. Also, if you're after raw performance you'd cache the indexer call in the loop like this: `var test = tests[i];` and then use this variable to access the fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example the performance difference is not essential, but the first variant is better in terms of code readability and flexibility.

You can use `struct` instead of `class` to avoid additional dereferencing operations, it will probably increase performance.

Answer (score 1):

Use struct not class and it will gave you performance,if you want to use class than second has more performance than first i think because of 1 object not 100 object in the heap